# How to add more than one new value to array via html form, in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to add new values in php array by html form. I wrote something like following in php:

```
$b=array();
$b[]=$_POST['unos'];
```

and something like this in html:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
<input type="number" name="unos"  id="unos">
</form>
```

And that code do the job, but only for one value. In other words, I am asking how to import more than one value in array. I add value="3"
     
in html input form, but that does not works, of course, or it is just one part of the answer. How to tell php to allow adding more than one value in array via html form?

UPDATE:

I want to import more values in one input field, that would be separated with "," for example, or whatever convention is.

UPDATE:

```
 <?php
 $unos=array();
 $unos[]=$_POST['unos'];
 $rezultat=count($unos); /*number of n's*/
 $zbir=array_sum($unos); /*total sum of n's*/
 $av=$zbir/$rezultat;    /*average value of n's*/
 echo "average value is $av</br>";
 }
 ?>
 <form action="?" method="post">
 <input type="number" name="unos"  id="unos">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

The code calculate average value of n's. I am beginner and just want to know how to add values of arrays by user via html.The reason I wanted to know how one can do that in 1 input file is because I do not want to limit number of values with number of input fields. I want make that user can add values as many as he want. Sorry, my English is not perfect.

Comment: Please put some more effort in explaining what you want. What is the desired result? Why don't you use more than 1 input fields?

Comment: Thanks, what you are suggesting is to make new html input field for every value of php array. But, I wanted to import more values in one input field, that would be separated with "," for example, or whatever convention is. But if there is no way to do such a thing, I should be satisfied with this. And what about that looping over $_POST['unos']?

Comment: Use nikhar's answer to turn `$_POST['unos']` into an array, the rest of your code looks correct. However, you also need to check whether `$_POST['submit']` is set, so you can tell whether you're printing the initial form or responding to the submission.

Comment: Another thing: You can use JavaScript to add inputs to your form dynamically, instead of typing everything into one field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="number" name="unos[]">
<input type="number" name="unos[]">
<input type="number" name="unos[]">
etc.
```

The above is standard for pulling form values into an array, but, given your update:

```
// Assuming "," separated values
   $unos = explode(",", $_POST['unos']);

   foreach ($unos as $item) {
       echo $item; // Do something with item
   }
```

Comment: That is precisely what I am looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you using `explode`? This technique doesn't create a comma-separated string, `$_POST['unos']` will be an array. See my answer.

Comment: @Barmar He's talking about taking "this,that,the-other" from **one** form field and then utilising it server-side using `$_POST['unos']`. None of us saw that until he posted an update.

Comment: I couldn't tell what you were talking about when you mentioned an update, since he didn't add it to the question. I only just noticed that he posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I didn't mention that in my comment - yes, as an answer. Otherwise, there are 4 very valid/similar answers (which I upvoted), which is always good to see.

Comment: Sorry if I made confusion with my vague post. I explained everything in detail in my new post. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about what you are asking, but I'm assuming you want to make `unos` into an array. You can do that like this:

```
<input type="number" name="unos[]"  id="unos0">
<input type="number" name="unos[]"  id="unos1">
<input type="number" name="unos[]"  id="unos2">
<input type="number" name="unos[]"  id="unos3">
<input type="number" name="unos[]"  id="unos4">
```

Then in order to access them via PHP just use `$_POST['unos'][$n]` where $n is an integer. You can also loop over `$_POST['unos']`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like that:

```
<form ...>
  <input type="text" name="unos[]" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="unos[]" value="2" />
</form>
```

The square brackets tell PHP to store the values into an array:

```
echo $_POST['unos'][0]; // "1"
echo $_POST['unos'][1]; // "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple form inputs, and give them an array-style name:

```
<form action="whatever.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="unos[]"/>
    <input type="number" name="unos[]"/>
    <input type="number" name="unos[]"/>
</form>
```

Then in the PHP you can access the array:

```
foreach($_POST['unos'] as $unos) {
    ...
}
```